# Nohup over ssh won't return

Tags: openssh, nohup

I am trying to do

```
[me@myPc]$ ssh me@server "nohup myBashScript.sh &"
```

My goal is to launch the process on the server, and then immediately return.

It is not working:
The job is started on server, but I still get the output on myPc and bash wait for completion prior to asking me for another command.

Why ? It's not supposed to !
Any way to avoid that ?

- myPc is `RHEL6.2`
- server is `ubuntu 10.04` and
- both runs `openssh`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As long as input or output are still open, ssh will keep the connection open. To solve this, make sure the input and output are not open.

For instance, use `ssh -n` and redirect your output:

```
ssh -n me@example.com "nohup myscript.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Comment: What if I still want `myscript.sh` to give me output, but the ssh session to still terminate after the script is done? In my case, the script itself starts nohup process, then returns. I was under the impression that `ssh -T` would help me do that.

Comment: @Gauthier Then just run the script without nohup.

Comment: I do. The script starts other commands with nohup and &, then terminates. But ssh doesn't return. The commands called in the script redirect stdout to files. Oh, but not stderr and stdin, could it be why?

Comment: There you have it! Input and output must be redirected.

Comment: What I don't understand is that if I actually login and get a tty, start the script that starts the nohup& commands, then I am allowed to logout from the ssh session. It doesn't complain that there are open input and output. Isn't that what `ssh -t` is supposed to mimic?

Answer (score 0):

Is it really necessary to run `nohup` via ssh? In my tests I did not find ANY difference running command with and without `nohup`. It seems that ssh does not send HUP anyway. This works equally as with `nohup`:

```
ssh me@server "myBashScript.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

The key to solution here is redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` as already mentioned in the accepted answer. Without it SSH reads from those descriptors, and returns only after they are closed.

Comment: Seriously doubt?) I literally put the command that works. I put it as a separate answer because it differs a lot from "another answer", and I doubt that the answer will be changed. As for no explanation about redirection - agree, added.

Comment: not only `nohup`, but also no stdin redirection. Ok, thanks, I think twice next time.

Comment: Actually the observation about stdin does justify a separate answer. I missed it because you originally concentrated on `nohup`. In a case like this it may be good to clearly state why your answer is better than the old answer. Example: "I know this old answer (link) solves the problem, but I think it is overzealous with `-n`. My tests indicate that stdin doesn't matter, `-n` is not needed; it's enough to redirect stdout and stderr, like this: … Also `nohup` is not needed. In my tests …". The solution first, simplification due to lack of `nohup` as a bonus.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the suggestion, I'll take to account next time.